# Cors-Problem when running a local node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I simply want to POST data from a js-script to a node-server application which i run with express.
When sending the data i get: CORS-Header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match with 'localhost:3000'.

**Client-Script:**

```
        let url = 'http://localhost:3000/api'
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: jsonData,
        };
        fetch(url, options)
```

**Server-Script:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening at 3000'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname))
const cors = require("cors")
app.use(cors({ origin: 'localhost:3000' }));


app.post('/api', (request, response) => {
    console.log(request)
})
```

If i open the network-analyzer from Firefox, this is what i get:

[fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bZPO.png)

How can i solve this issue?!

Thanks a Lot,

Max

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: Also instead of fetch try https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent

Answer (score 1):

Use this extension for local development

[Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en)

Comment: I already did, but this didn't really resolve anything, thse are my options: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ORIGIN (i tried "*" as well, but that didn't help at all). I've also white-listed http://localhost:3000, http://localhost:3000/api, http://localhost, localhost.

Answer (score 0):

**If you add:**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
```

it works just fine!

src: https://dzone.com/articles/cors-in-node

Answer (score 0):

I think `app.use(cors({ origin: 'localhost:3000' }));` should be `app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000' }));`
https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuring-cors